# Content of out of bound array element in x86 assembly tasm

Tags: arrays, assembly, memory, tasm

So I have this assembly program that changes the content of an array. What is the content of the array and what is the value of array_length after the execution?
The problem is that on the second call of procedure Procm, si = 10 then si = 16 but my array length is 9. What's the content of ax after mov ax, array[si]? Is it the content of a memory address?

```
DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 200h
.DATA
array dw 9 ,8 ,7 ,6 ,5 ,4 ,3 ,2 ,1
array_length EQU $-array
l1 EQU 3

.CODE

    start: mov ax, @DATA
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, 2*l1-2
    call Procm
    mov si, 4*l1-2
    call Procm
    mov si, 6*l1-2
    call Procm
    mov si, 6*l1-2
    call Procm
    mov si, 6*l1-2
    call Procm
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
    Procm PROC NEAR
    mov cx, l1-1
    mov ax, array[si]
    B1: mov bx, array[si-2]
    mov array[si], bx
    sub si, 2
    loop B1
    mov array[si], ax
    FIN: ret
    Procm ENDP
    nop 

end start
```

Comment: You haven't specified which assembler you're using, but it looks like TASM or MASM. In that case, `mov ax, array[si]` means `ax = 16-bit value at address si+array`.

Comment: Indexing is in bytes. Your array has words, 2 bytes each. Hence length is 18 bytes. Your indices are within bounds. PS: looks like you messed up the `l1` vs `11` ...

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I understand now.